# Calculate xy coordinates to annotate Stem Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

**Background:**

I have created a **bar chart** as follows:

- x axis: `numbers` (ndarray)
- y axis: number `frequencies` (ndarray)
- each frequency bar has the actual value annotated at the top of the
  respective bar; to do this a have created a custom function `annotations()`, which makes use of `plt.bar` functions `get_x, get_height, get_width` to calculate the exact position where my label will be positioned

**Using plt.bar():** - this works fine

```
numbers=np.array([1,2,3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,12])
frequencies=np.array([233,266,261,220,245,231,235,263,246,169,159, 58])

x = np.arange(1,len(numbers)+1)
bars=plt.bar(x, frequencies, width=0.5)

plt.xticks(numbers)

def annotations():
    for bar in bars:
        height = bar.get_height()
        plt.annotate('{}'.format(height),
                    xy=(bar.get_x() + bar.get_width() / 2, height),
                    xytext=(0, 1),  # 1 points vertical offset
                    textcoords="offset points",
                    ha='center', va='bottom')

annotations()

#plt.hist(frequencies, numbers)

plt.show()
```

**Bar Chart:**

[image: bar chart]

**Goal:** 
*Create a **Stem Chart** with annotated labels over each stem, similar to the bar chart above*.

**My plt.stem():**

```
x = np.arange(1, len(numbers) + 1)  # the label locations; needs to start at 1, not 0
print(x)
stems = plt.stem(x, frequencies)
```

[image: stem chart]

**Question:**
How do I calculate the correct xy coordinates on a stem chart to place custom labels, in this case `frequencies`? The limitation here is that, unlike plt.bar(), plt.stem() does not have `get_x, get_height()` functions.

Comment: You don't need to loop over the bars. Instead you can loop over `x` and `y`; this would then work for bars and stems and lines and...everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already have the height of the stems in your variable `frequencies`, so you don't need to try to extract them from the artists.

```
numbers=np.array([1,2,3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,12])
frequencies=np.array([233,266,261,220,245,231,235,263,246,169,159, 58])

stems = plt.stem(numbers, frequencies)
plt.xticks(numbers, numbers)
for x,y in zip(numbers, frequencies):
    plt.annotate('{:.0f}'.format(y), xy=(x,y), xytext=(0,5), textcoords='offset points',ha='center')
```

[image]

PS: as @ImportanceOfBeingErnest commented, this is also the case for your barplot, you could use the exact same code to annotate the bar plot.